# nextjs - multer to supabase file not uploading correctly

Tags: javascript, next.js, multer, supabase

I have a nextjs app where a file is sent to the nextjs api, multer uploads it to the server and then supabase uploads it to the database. The file seems to be uploading fine and showing the correct size on the db, but when you download it, the file is 1kb and seems to contain no data.
Multer setup:

```
// Multer setup
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'public/uploads/');
   },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null , uuidv4()+file.originalname);
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage, limits: { fileSize: 10*1024*1024 } });
```

(the uploads file does exist at public/uploads and the file shows there as an mp4 and plays correctly)
The supabase upload:

```
const supabaseUrl = process.env.SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseKey = process.env.SUPABASE_KEY
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)
...
router
.post(upload.single('video'), async (req, res) => {
  const file = req.file
  const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
    .from('uploads')
    .upload(file.filename, file, {
      contentType: file.mimetype
    })
```

An example of req.file:

```
{
  fieldname: 'video',
  originalname: 'file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'video/mp4',
  destination: 'public/uploads/',
  filename: '8b7c4570-2b5a-4cbd-aab9-5c26323b0adcfile_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4',
  path: 'public\\uploads\\8b7c4570-2b5a-4cbd-aab9-5c26323b0adcfile_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4',
  size: 1570024
}
```

I think the supabase upload isn't working / not sending the right file as without a mimetype specified it just uploads a plaint/text.
Let me know if any further code or info is needed.

Comment: From your example above `req.file` is just a json object which would be stored as a string when you call the Supabase storage upload function. You need to convert the actual video data into bytes to be stored into storage rather then `req.file` which is only a string.